# Pandas add dataframes side to side with different indexes

Tags: pandas

I have dataframes like this:

```
        Sender                    USD_Equivalent
725     ABC                               5777527.31
330     CFE                               4717812.90
12      CDE                               3085838.19

        Sender                    USD_Equivalent
707     AAP                               1962412.94
149     EFF                               1777705.37
189     EFG                               1744705.37
```

And I want them like this :

```
Sender     USD_Equivalent   Sender   USD_Equivalent
 ABC         5777527.31      AAP       1962412.94
 CFE         4717812.90      EFF       1777705.37
 CDE         3085838.19      EFG       1744705.37
```

Thanks

Comment: `pd.concat` with `ignore_index` keyword should work.

Comment: Why would you want duplicate column names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [df1, df2]], axis=1)

  Sender  USD_Equivalent Sender  USD_Equivalent
0    ABC      5777527.31    AAP      1962412.94
1    CFE      4717812.90    EFF      1777705.37
2    CDE      3085838.19    EFG      1744705.37
```

Comment: There's always a room for improvement +1