# print out two or more dataframes in jupyter (python) side by side

Tags: python, html, pandas, printing

I'm trying print two or more dataframe in the output of jupyter notebook cell using Python. Actually I am using a function from Wes Mckinney that perform this work but the dataframes don't have headers. I would like that each table has title specifying the name of each table, of course. I need a function similar to *function(dfs,names_dfs=[''])*

The function that actually I am using is

```
def side_by_side(*objs, **kwds): 
    from pandas.io.formats.printing import adjoin
    space = kwds.get('space', 7)
    reprs = [repr(obj).split('\n') for obj in objs]
    print(adjoin(space, *reprs))
```

I hope you can help me. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter is just the interpreter for python. So you don’t need to do anything special other than format the python output, like what’s done in this post: [How to make two plots side-by-side using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42818361/how-to-make-two-plots-side-by-side-using-python)

Or here is another post explaining how to concatenate two dataframes for display: [Pandas add dataframes side to side with different indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420740/pandas-add-dataframes-side-to-side-with-different-indexes)